# Apache POI XWPFTableRow remove column Word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, cell

I am trying to create a function in Java which removes a column from a Word table with header name "Serious". Please find this function below. When I run the code nothing is happening. Has anyone had any issues using the `removeCell` function?

```
public static void remCells(XWPFTable table) {
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.getNumberOfRows(); rowIndex++) {

        XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.getTableCells().size()-1; colIndex++) {
            XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(colIndex);

            if(table.getRow(5).getCell(colIndex).getText().equals("Serious")) {
                row.removeCell(colIndex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you check first the invocation result of the `removeCell` method?

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it, you mean should I put in try/catch ?

Comment: I mean, just print out the result of `row.removeCell(colIndex)` with `System.out.println` or into a log file

Comment: PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: wait. what version of apache-poi you're using? because it should returned boolean.

Comment: exaclty same problem here, did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Found solution here :
https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow/removeCell

We have to do

```
row.getCtRow().removeTc(colIndex);
```

before

```
row.removeCell(colIndex);
```

Comment: Working answer. Weird fact, that removing row doesn't require getCTTbl().removeTr(index) and works fine with only  removeRow(index)